# Variable in first .append is unknown

Tags: jquery

I generate the right number of popup boxes that pops up when I click the link. There I determine their quantity, click generate, and depending on how much I chose them, adds them to the respective div. In generated boxes there is p, which also has an onclick. It activates an anonymous function and adds the input and next button. In this insertion I add a link to the image. As for example, by adding 5 inputs, four are working, then the first one has src unknown. What is the problem here?

```js
inputval = 0;
$("#incrementer").on("click", function() {
  inputval = $(".param1").val();
  if (inputval < 5) {
    inputval++;
    $(".param1").val(inputval);
  } else {
    alert("Error! Max five elements");
  }
});

$("#decrementer").on("click", function() {
  inputval = $(".param1").val();
  inputval--;
  if (inputval <= 0) {
    inputval = 0;
  }
  $(".param1").val(inputval);
});

function popup(enabled) {
  switch (enabled) {
    case "enable":
      $("#popup").css("display", "block");
      break;

    case "disabled":
      $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
      break;
  }
}

function param(type) {
  $("#generate").off();
  field = $(".param1").val();

  switch (type) {
    case "optional":
      if (field == 1) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-1-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 2) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-2-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 3) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-3-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 4) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-4-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 5) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-5-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else {
        alert("Error!");
      }
      
      $(".test").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" name="param2" id="param2" placeholder="Path to img" /><button type="button" class="submit-btn">Add</button>');
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        pathtoimg = $("#param2").val();

        $(".submit-btn").on("click", function() {
          $(this).parent().append('<img style="width: 100%;" src="' + pathtoimg + '" />');
          $(this).fadeOut("slow");
          $(this).prev().fadeOut("slow");
        });
      });
      break;
  }
}

$("#optional").on("click", function() {
  popup("enable");

  $("#generate").on("click", function() {
    param("optional");
  });
});

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  popup("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="optional">Additional box</a>
<div id="popup" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); width: 500px; left: 50%; margin-left: -250px; background: #000; color: #fff; display: none;">
  <p>Params <button type="button" id="close">x</button></p>
  <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 173px;">
    <button type="button" id="incrementer" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 21px; width: 21px; border: 0;">+</button>
    <button type="button" id="decrementer" style="position: absolute; right: 21px; top: 0; height: 21px; width: 21px; border: 0;">-</button>
    <input class="param1" type="text" placeholder="0" value="" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
  <div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: I did not really understand your problem description; But as long as you are creating a structure that ends up having the same ID in the document multiple times, don’t expect correct results on anything ... IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Where have i multiple id in HTML code? I don't see it

Comment: Add two boxes, click both the "Add optional img" texts ... results in two input fields with id `param2` at the same time ...

Comment: You were right about id's. I change this into a classes and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `input` value before `submit` click.

You need to get `input` value when user click on `submit` like below and it will work.

```
 $(".submit-btn").on("click", function() {
              pathtoimg = $(this).prev().val();
```

Remove `pathtoimg = $("#param2").val();` on `.test` click.

```js
inputval = 0;
$("#incrementer").on("click", function() {
  inputval = $(".param1").val();
  if (inputval < 5) {
    inputval++;
    $(".param1").val(inputval);
  } else {
    alert("Error! Max five elements");
  }
});

$("#decrementer").on("click", function() {
  inputval = $(".param1").val();
  inputval--;
  if (inputval <= 0) {
    inputval = 0;
  }
  $(".param1").val(inputval);
});

function popup(enabled) {
  switch (enabled) {
    case "enable":
      $("#popup").css("display", "block");
      break;

    case "disabled":
      $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
      break;
  }
}

function param(type) {
  $("#generate").off();
  field = $(".param1").val();

  switch (type) {
    case "optional":
      if (field == 1) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-1-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 2) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-2-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 3) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-3-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 4) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-4-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else if (field == 5) {
        for (counter = 0; counter < field; counter++) {
          $("#example").append('<div class="grid-5-5"><p class="test">Add optional img</p></div>');
        }
      } else {
        alert("Error!");
      }

      $(".test").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" name="param2" class="param2" placeholder="Path to img" /><button type="button" class="submit-btn">Add</button>');
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");

        $(".submit-btn").on("click", function() {
          pathtoimg = $(this).prev().val();
          $(this).parent().append('<img style="width: 100%;" src="' + pathtoimg + '" />');
          $(this).fadeOut("slow");
          $(this).prev().fadeOut("slow");
        });
      });
      break;
  }
}

$("#optional").on("click", function() {
  popup("enable");

  $("#generate").on("click", function() {
    param("optional");
  });
});

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  popup("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="optional">Additional box</a>
<div id="popup" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); width: 500px; left: 50%; margin-left: -250px; background: #000; color: #fff; display: none;">
  <p>Params <button type="button" id="close">x</button></p>
  <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 173px;">
    <button type="button" id="incrementer" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 21px; width: 21px; border: 0;">+</button>
    <button type="button" id="decrementer" style="position: absolute; right: 21px; top: 0; height: 21px; width: 21px; border: 0;">-</button>
    <input class="param1" type="text" placeholder="0" value="" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
  <div id="example"></div>
```